Uniform Fréchet Differentiability of a series of norms
I'm studying Theorem 9.14 from "Banach Space Theory",Fabian M. et al, which characterizes super-reflexivity. One of the steps of the proof is to show that 2 and 3 imply 4. So, using two equivalent norms, one uniformly convex and the other uniformly Fréchet differentiable, they construct a new norm that is uniformly convex and uniformly Fréchet differentiable, denoted by $\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\cdot\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert$ and defined as $\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert x\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}\frac{\lVert x\rVert_n^2}{2^n}$. Then, they say that, since the derivative of $\lVert\cdot\rVert_n^2$ is bounded in bounded sets for all $n\geq 1$, then $\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\cdot\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert$ (although in the book they write $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, which I think is a mistake) is uniformly Fréchet differentiable. I've been thinking about this and, even I saw it as a pretty natural conclusion, I'm not able to prove it. I've tried using Weierstrass $M$-test but can't bound the sums by something not depending on $n$. Also, I've found this result that serie that (skipping details) the series of Fréchet differentiable functions is Fréchet differentiable and the series of derivatives is the derivative of the series, but they don't say nothing about uniformity, so maybe I lose it using this result.
So thank you for reading and I hope someone can help me. I would really appreciate it!
See you!
